# Prove with Euclid's Algortihm

Tags: proof-writing, euclidean-algorithm

I have this problem and I'm not 100% how to complete it. Here's the question:

> Let $m$ and $k$ be positive integers with $m > 1, k > 1$.  Show that
>    $\gcd(m, mk - 1)=1$.  (Hint: use Euclid's algorithm.)

I get the hint, so I set it up like this: $$mk-1=m+1$$However, I'm not sure where to go from here. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: 
\begin{align*}
mk-1&=m\cdot(k-1)+m-1 \\
m&=1\cdot(m-1)+1.
\end{align*}

Comment: So you get $m=m$ at the end... how does that prove the $\gcd=1$?

Comment: @KFC Note that the last nonzero remainder is 1, implying that $\gcd(mk-1, m)=1$.